# What was the War Cry in Ramayana and Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, vishnu, ramayana, war

I saw somewhere that in both Ramayana and Mahabharata, the warriors of both sides(as in Ramayana and Mahabharata most of the characters were Shiva devotees) used to say "Har Har Mahadev" as War cry. Can anyone give me some shashtra references regarding this? And if wasn't Har Mahadev... then what was the war cry ?